# Customize cursor in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I customize a cursor in the EditText. Input something and find that if the cursor at the end of the EditText, it looks thin. I don't know why.
Here's my code.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="@dimen/2dip" />
    <solid android:color="@color/edit_cursor" />
    <padding android:top="@dimen/dimen_1_dip" android:bottom="@dimen/dimen_1_dip" />
</shape>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Above description is not enough to understand your problem. Your question must have enough specification to get more attention.

Comment: android:ems="10" solves the issue in this case

Answer (score 1):

```
    <EditText

    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

   color_cursor.xml


   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <size android:width="1dp" />
   <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"  />
   </shape>
```